# How can I prevent immediate shutdown of my application

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My application gets a uri of mongodb database and makes an instace of Mongoclient.

```js
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
const config = require("../config");

const uri = config.dbAdress;

const client = new MongoClient(uri);

const foo = async () => {
  try {
    await client.connect();
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    await client.close();
  }
}
```

If the uri is invalid it throws an MongoParseError and immediately shutdowns the app.

```js
throw new MongoParseError(`Invalid connection string "${uri}"`);
```

I use pkg to make an executable file, and when the uri is invalid the window is closing.
How can I handle it and prevent the shutdown, or at least wait some time to actually read the error message?

I tried to wrap it in try/catch, but then I lose the access to the variable.

```js
try {
  const client new MongoClient(uri);
} catch(e) {
  console.error(e);
  setTimeout(() => {console.log('')}, 5000);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by you are losing access to the variable inside try/catch? Secondly, you are only initializing the client inside the try. You did not actually connect to the MongoDB server.

Comment: what is in config?

Comment: @Ammar Under my try/catch I have a class with static methods which suppose to use this client variable, but inside those methods the client is undefined

Comment: @barrypicker
```const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const json = fs.readFileSync(
  path.join(path.dirname(process.execPath), "config.json"),
  "utf-8"
);

const config = JSON.parse(json);

module.exports = config;```

Answer (score 1):

I've wrapped it in try/catch and use "var" keyword to get rid of context.

```js
try {
  var client = new MongoClient(uri);
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
  setTimeout(() => {console.log('')}, 5000);
}
```